# Python regex partially case insensitive

Tags: python, regex, case-insensitive

How to do it in nice short way? I have 2 strings and I want to search one in another, but:

> - lowercase letter matches to lower- and uppercase
> - uppercase letter matches only to uppercase.

Example:

`"abcd"` matches to `"AbCd"`, `"ABCD"`, or `"abcd"`

`"Abcd"` matches to `"Abcd"`, `"ABcd"` and so on, but not matches to `"abcd"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to transform your regular expressions, something like

```
def transform(regex):
    return ''.join([
        "[%s%s]" % (c, c.upper())
            if c.islower()
            else c
        for c in regex
    ])


transformed = transform('Abcd')
```

Will transform the regex `Abcd` into `A[bB][cC][dD]`.

Of course this does *not* work, if your actual regex does have character classes `[a-z]` already.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function :

```
>>> def match(s1,s2):
...    if len(s2)!=len(s2):
...          return False
...    else :
...          return all(i==j if i.isupper() else i==j.lower() for i,j in zip(s1,s2))
...
```

Demo :

```
>>> match('Abcd','aBcd')
False
>>> match('Abcd','ABcd')
True
>>> match('AbCd','ABcd')
False
>>> match('AbCd','ABCd')
True
```

In this function first you compare the length of your strings together then you need to compare each letters in your strings together that you can do it with `zip` function, so if the first letter was an upper case you just compare the letters as they are (this is `True` just if both was equal and second was upper like first) but if the first letter was lower you compare the first letter with lower case of second.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is walking the string you want to match and if you find a lowercase letter, make the regular expression case insensitive by putting it in `[character|CHARACTER]`, and if the character is already uppercase, then force it to be uppercase (just leave it as is).

I've created a simple test with three sample outputs (as strings to match with) that are stored in `input_string` and four sample strings to match agains (what in the example below is stored in `test_string`.

```
import re

for input_string in ['abcd', 'Abcd', 'abCD']:
    created_regex = ''
    for character in input_string:
        if character.islower():
            created_regex += '[%s%s]' % (character, character.upper())
        else:
            created_regex += character

    regex = re.compile(created_regex)
    for test_string in ['AbCd', 'abcd', 'ABCD', 'ABcd']:
        print ('From input_string="%s". Does %s match %s ? %s'
                % (input_string, test_string, created_regex,
                   regex.match(test_string) is not None))
```

This outputs:

```
From input_string="abcd". Does AbCd match [aA][bB][cC][dD] ? True
From input_string="abcd". Does abcd match [aA][bB][cC][dD] ? True
From input_string="abcd". Does ABCD match [aA][bB][cC][dD] ? True
From input_string="abcd". Does ABcd match [aA][bB][cC][dD] ? True
From input_string="Abcd". Does AbCd match A[bB][cC][dD] ? True
From input_string="Abcd". Does abcd match A[bB][cC][dD] ? False
From input_string="Abcd". Does ABCD match A[bB][cC][dD] ? True
From input_string="Abcd". Does ABcd match A[bB][cC][dD] ? True
From input_string="abCD". Does AbCd match [aA][bB]CD ? False
From input_string="abCD". Does abcd match [aA][bB]CD ? False
From input_string="abCD". Does ABCD match [aA][bB]CD ? True
From input_string="abCD". Does ABcd match [aA][bB]CD ? False
```